# xcode 6.1 iOS 7 does scaling occur if only supply 1 image in image.xcassets

Tags: ios, xcode, image, assets

Take a look at this image:[image]

I have an image in the center in the 2x placeholder.  Its just a slightly grey image.

its from the image.xcassets folder in xcode 6.1.
If i dont put an image in the first and third place holders will the image get scaled down to 1x and likewise scaled up to 3x ?

the project im building is for all screen sizes.  if it does scale is it best practice to put a image in the 2x and have it scale up and down or 3x and have it scale downwards.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? Seems like a better approach than posting a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what we do and scaling does apply. Upscaling looks blurry and isn't a good idea generally but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

To us just a single image for all the scales you can better use the Vector Image which is now available in xcode 6 and above. Try using that.

This is its example to use: [Use vector image in ios](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2014/09/vector-images-xcode6/)